# MSI - How to know when a particular MSI is running

Tags: windows-installer, upgrade

Is there a simply way to know when an msi is running? (either in silent or no silent mode.) Maybe using and MSI API? Reading from somewhere?...

I need this in order to avoid launching a program coded in C++.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it your program? And is it your program that you upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any API for detecting running installers. Also, an MSI installation has two sequences:

- the installation UI -> [InstallUISequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369543%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- the actual installation process -> [InstallExecuteSequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369500%28VS.85%29.aspx)

InstallUISequence uses a process which runs under the current user account.
InstallExecuteSequence uses a process which is a child of the Windows Installer service.

So there's not an easy way for detecting a running installation. The only solution I can think of is enumerating all open windows and trying to find an installation dialog by name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cosmin.I can't stand how installer managed this situations. For instance, in my case I have to do an upgrade, so, within the process of upgrading I have the possibility to run the main application (which of course is being updating)...

Comment: @Santiago Is it the installer than starts your application during upgrade? I see no problem here: you can start the installed application when upgrade is complete.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov I'm using the <RemoveExistingProducts After='InstallFinalize'/> strategy (took from http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa371197.aspx) So, the key here is that I'm upgrading my product and in the middle of the process I will double click my application and will open (I'm just thinking if something can gets bad if that executable file is being upgrading.) Thanks!

Comment: This is a very unlikely scenario. A simpler approach would be to just close the application when your installation starts.